# Comparison operators in multimatch query in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to filter a elastic search query to find salary of a employee greater than or less than a particular amount.What should be the filtered query??

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 24,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "claims",
                    "fields": ["Employee"],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "type": "unified",
        "fields": {
            "*": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that for range query,

```
"query": {
        "range" : {
            "salary" : {
                "gte" : "1000",
                "lt" :  "3000"
            }
        }
    }
```